# TypeScript won't allow arithmetic operators but I don't understand why

Tags: typescript, numbers

Why does TypeScript give the `Operator '+' cannot be applied` error in this case? The number types are essentially unchanged. I've got an unusual coding situation where I want to remove the built-in methods on `number`, like `toExponential`, but want math operators to still work. Is there some kind of #pragma or something to let this work?

```
let x: Omit<number, 'banana'> = 1;
let y: Omit<number, 'banana'> = 2;
let z = x + y;
```

Comment: "I've got an unusual coding situation where I want to remove the built-in methods on number...but want math operators to still work" why? If you are trying to do lots of number crunching and want unboxed arithmetic (setting aside for a minute the desirability of doing so in JS, or even whether or not the JIT will unbox it for you) you're probably better off compiling C to wasm.

Comment: The security rules for Google Firebase server are written in a language exceedingly similar to javascript and there is no nice code editor for it. So i'm trying to write them locally in TypeScript and trying to hide the methods on the primitives that aren't available in that other environment. Then I'll copy/paste my code.

Comment: They provide a [spec with a formal grammar](https://github.com/google/cel-spec/blob/master/doc/langdef.md) for the language. It would probably be easier to find or even write a plugin for your editor of choice than to bend Typescript's type system in this particular way. Nice way to get some practical practice with parsing and do the world (or at least users of your favorite text editor) a favor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The + operator doesn't work on that type. Relevant section from the spec:

> **4.19.2 The + operator**
>
> **The binary + operator requires both operands to be of the Number primitive type** or an enum type, or at
> least one of the operands to be of type Any or the String primitive type. Operands of an enum type are
> treated as having the primitive type Number. If one operand is the null or undefined value, it is treated
> 84
> as having the type of the other operand. If both operands are of the Number primitive type, the result is
> of the Number primitive type. If one or both operands are of the String primitive type, the result is of the
> String primitive type. Otherwise, the result is of type Any.

(emphasis mine)

Source: https://javascript.xgqfrms.xyz/pdfs/TypeScript%20Language%20Specification.pdf

Comment: But by "duck typing" I haven't changed anything about the number type?

Comment: But it's not the *primitive* number type anymore.

Comment: don’t understand. I thought typescript uses duck typing and the shape of the data should be exactly the same since I’m omitting a non existent property.

Comment: The type `'Pick<number, "toString" | "toFixed" | "toExponential" | "toPrecision" | "valueOf" | "toLocaleString">'` is not a primitive type, and it's very different from the type `'number'`.